# Get orders REST API problem

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

I am trying to get orders for a specific customer through API:

GET on      https://domain.com/index.php/rest/V1/orders

and header parameter is

```
Authorization Bearer x1v9pvmag5rvkb0vgekpdtwri6ak1pxh
```

but also get error

```
{"message":"Consumer is not authorized to access %resources","parameters":{"resources":"Magento_Sales::sales"}}
```

Please help.

Comment: Can you post your GET data?

Comment: I didn't get any data except the error

Comment: I mean the passed data to this api?

Comment: I didn't pass any data. only the header authorization parameter.

Comment: What about posting your permissions for the role associated with that bearer?

Comment: Why not try the username and password for a customer account instead of the admin account information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have curl installed, you can use the following command to get a token.  Replace the following:

- BASE_URL is your magento 2 domain, like https://domain.com
- ADMIN_NAME is the username that you use to login to the admin backend
- ADMIN_PASSWORD is the password that you to login to the admin backend

`curl -X POST "BASE_URL/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"username": "ADMIN_NAME", "password": "ADMIN_PASSWORD"}'`

It will return a token.  Copy that token and try your get again. To do it with curl, you can try the following.  I added searchCriteria to only get the first 10 records.  You have to escape [] with \ in curl.  Also, make sure you replace BASE_URL and TOKEN:

`curl -X GET "BASE_URL/index.php/rest/V1/orders/?searchCriteria\[currentPage\]=1&searchCriteria\[pageSize\]=10" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer TOKEN"`